# Find next separator ksh

Tags: unix, ksh, separator

i have a file created by a spool. This file has columns separated by a separator : `#@;`
Is there a way to find the data between the separator? I mean for example :

```
#@;Hello #@;World #@;!!!
```

i have to find hello then world then !!!. I tried this way but doesn't work:

```
tp=${ENDFL##*@#}
          HELLOSTRING=`printf '"%s"\n' "${tp%%#@;*}"`
```

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: You can use `awk` with the `-F` option and print the appropriate value with `$1` etc -- but what do you ultimately want to do with this data anyway?

Comment: something like `awk -F'"#@;"' '{print $1}'`? However an insert.

Comment: That would rather be `awk -F'#@;'`. And what "insert"?

Comment: An insert from the spool created before with the dates. The important thing now is "convert", if possible, this `tp=${ENDFL##*@#}`
          `HELLOSTRING=`printf '"%s"\n' "${tp%%#@;*}"`` in this your solution `awk -F'#@;'` and have the same result. My way shows blank all fields and i think because it stops at the first separator.

Comment: I think i have to do something like a while on the `awk -F'#@;'` because i want that read and find the "next" separator. for example i have to find that between the first separator and the second there is Hello, between second and third world etc etc.. Understand now?

Comment: Simple, example data (as you have) and required output from that data eliminate a lot of problems generated trying to verbally describe your goal. Please consider editing your question to show required output, VS the current output you are getting. If it's not obvious why your current output isn't right, then some notes about that. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use translate command:

```
  echo "#@;Hello #@;World #@;!!!"  | tr '#@;' '^' | tr -s '^'
```

Output:

```
 Kaizen ~
 $ echo "#@;Hello #@;World #@;!!!"  | tr '#@;' '^' | tr -s '^'
   ^Hello ^World ^!!!
```

Explanation:

The first tr replaces the '#@;' delimiter with ^ , but it does that three times.

"# , @ , ;" are three separate literals so it subs ^ for all three separately

The second tr suppresses the occurrence of multiple ^ to one.

Hence you get a ^ delimited output as "^Hello ^World ^!!!"

For your file just cat filename then pipe it to the translate command after which you can use AWK, cut or whatever to format or extract as per you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to deal with a bunch of lines

```
sed -e 's/#@;//g' input.dat
```

To find the data between the separator (assuming you have the value in a variable as suggested by `tp=`)

```
echo "${tp/#@;/}"
```

If you want to work with the parts

```
origIFS=$IFS        # always kep the original $IFS save
IFS='§'            # define a InputFieldSeparator which will not be used in your input
set ${tp//#@;/$IFS} # reduce separator to one char and set $1 ... based on that separator
IFS=$origIFS        # and restore $IFS when you are done
echo "'$1' '$2' '$3' '$4'"  # note that $1 is empty, it is before the first separator)
```